# success_url doesn't redirect to redirect page

Tags: django, django-views

Please help me out. My success_url doesn't redirect to the redirect page specified. I've tried using HttpResponseRedirect, reverse_lazy, and reverse. All gives the same issue.

Views:

```
class SignUp(FormView):
    template_name = 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html'
    form_class = ClientForm
    success_url = HttpResponseRedirect("home")

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ClientForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ClientForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            Client.objects.create(name=name, schema_name=name, domain_url=name + ".localhost")
            # return render(request, 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html', {'form': form})
        return render(request, 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html', {'form': form})
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUp.as_view(), name="sign_up"),
    path('home/', include(router.urls), name='home'),
    path("register", signup, name="register")

]
```

html page:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Create Account">
</form>
```

Comment: *All gives the same issue.*, What issue?

Comment: They don't redirect to the redirect page specified.

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: No, I haven't  got any all.

Comment: This is because you have *overridden* the **`post(...)`** and you are calling redirect methods.

Comment: what's the solution please?

Comment: I just tried adding **return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home"))** within the post and it isn't recognising "home" as a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: you can simply do success_url = '/home/'